# How to add target file depending of called tag in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm using these Makefile basically for all my projects, adapting it for the different type of libraries or executable that I need to generate. 
These times I need to compile different targets that have several common files and a single file that depends of the different targets.

I try something like that

```
# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target

RM := rm -rf
CXX:= g++
LD := g++
CC := gcc

TARGET = ../../Libs/libdemo.so

# definition of additional libraries for linking
LIBS := -L/data/somelib_lib/ -lsomelib1 -lsomelib2 
# definition of include directories
# for each you need to add -I
INCLUDE :=  -I../../include 

#compiler definition 

CFLAGS= -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP   -D __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP


# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 



LINKER_FLAG= -shared

target1: CPP_SRCS += \
        src/main1.cpp

target1: CPP_DEPS += \
        src/main1.d

target1: CFLAGS += -O0 -g3
target1: LINKER_FLAG += -g   
target1: $(TARGET)
    @echo "main1 called"

target2: CPP_SRCS += \
        src/main2.cpp

target2: CPP_DEPS += \
        src/main2.d

target2: CFLAGS += -O0 -g3
target2: LINKER_FLAG += -g   
target2: $(TARGET)
    @echo "main2 called"


profile: CFLAGS += -pg 
profile: $(TARGET)
    @echo "profile called"

valgrind: CFLAGS += -g -O1  
valgrind: LINKER_FLAG += -g   
valgrind: $(TARGET)

all: CFLAGS += -O3
all: $(TARGET)
    @echo "all called"

CPP_SRCS += \
    ../src/file1.cpp \
    ../src/file2.cpp \
    ../src/LoadParams.cpp \
    ../src/file3.cpp  \


CPP_DEPS += \
    ./src/file1.d \
    ./src/file2.d \
    ./src/LoadParams.d \
    ./src/file3.d  \

OBJECTDIR = ./
OBJECTS=$(CPP_SRCS:%.cpp=$(OBJECTDIR)%.o)


# Tool invocations
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    $(LD) $(LIBS) $(LINKER_FLAG) -o "$@" $(OBJECTS) 
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS)
    $(RM) $(CPP_DEPS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

clean:
    @echo "clean called"
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS)
    $(RM) $(CPP_DEPS)

#echo "$@ and $^"

$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler'
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

The problem now is that if I call make target1 the compiler compiles only 4 files without including the file main1.cpp, while during the linking the command includes 5 .o files and of course the main1.o file is missing. 
These means that the $(OBJECTS) is generated correctly but after the variable CPP_SRC does not contain the main1.cpp file. 
Could some one explaining this strange behaviour and give me some hints on how to solve properly the issues (or suggested a better way to perform the same task) ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have (at least) two targets, `target1` and `target2` that build the file `libdemo.so` with different contents. Are you sure you want it that way?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure. The example is kept simple to show the problematic behaviour, the real one is much more articulate with also change in compilation flags, but these is not the point. The final scope is to use different implementation of some part of the code if we want i.e. real time / not real time behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is here:

```
target1: CPP_SRCS += src/main1.cpp
```

This is a [target-specific variable assignment](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific), so it is available in the *body* of the rule (and of the rules of prerequisites), but not in the *prerequisite list* of the rule (or of the prerequisites). So this:

```
OBJECTS=$(CPP_SRCS:%.cpp=$(OBJECTDIR)%.o)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    ...
```

will not put `main1.o` in the prerequisite list. If that isn't clear, try this:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo the variable OBJECTS contains $(OBJECTS)
    @echo but the prerequisite list is $^
```

There are a couple of ways to approach the solution, but be aware that since **`target1` and `target2` both build `libdemo.so`,** there will be no perfect solution.

One way is to give the libraries different names:

```
libdemo1.so: main1.o

libdemo2.so: main2.o

libdemo1.so libdemo2.so: $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Building target: $@ from objects: $^
    $(LD) $(LIBS) $(LINKER_FLAG) -o $@ $^
```

Another is to use recursion:

```
target1: main1.o
    @$(MAKE) $(TARGET) CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) LINKER_FLAG=$(LINKER_FLAG)
```